# Would my algorithm benefit in terms of speed from vectorization and what could that look like?

Tags: python

I want to use the values in each row of the df as parameters to simulate data N times and store sum of simulated data somewhere.

The reproducible example works - but as N gets larger in combination with more rows in df it becomes very time consuming.

Is there a way to optimize? I have been looking into vectorization and maybe using multiple generators to pipeline the operations or list comprehension but am stuck.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pert import PERT

data = [[0.1, 0.14, 0.25, 50, 100, 150], [0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 200, 250, 300]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])

N = 1000
confidence = 4

empty_list = []

for _ in range(N):
    df["P"] = df.apply(lambda x: PERT(x.A, x.B, x.C, confidence).rvs(1), axis = 1).astype(float)
    df["O"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.random.binomial(1, x.P, 1), axis = 1).astype(int)
    df["L"] = df.apply(lambda x: PERT(x.D, x.E, x.F, confidence).rvs(1) if x.O == 1 else 0, axis = 1).astype(int)
    empty_list.append(sum(df["L"]))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(empty_list, columns = ["L"])

P50 = np.percentile(df1["L"], 50).astype(int)
```

Comment: Are you using the pertdist package? https://pypi.org/project/pertdist/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer was using a general attempt to vectorization, not knowing what `PERT` really was and where it was from. Assuming that `PERT` is from `pertdist`, there is a much shorter and easier way to vectorize the code. The other answer is still useful for people that come here with a slightly different problem.

---

`PERT` directly allows to draw more than one sample.
That makes things a lot easier.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pert import PERT  # pertdist package

data = [[0.1, 0.14, 0.25, 50, 100, 150], [0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 200, 250, 300]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])

N = 1000
confidence = 4

P = PERT(df["A"], df["B"], df["C"], confidence).rvs((N, len(df)))
O = np.random.binomial(np.ones(len(df), dtype=int), P)
L = PERT(df["D"], df["E"], df["F"], confidence).rvs((N, len(df)))
L = np.where(O == 1, L, 0).astype(int)
data1 = np.sum(L, axis=1)
P50 = np.percentile(df1["L"], 50).astype(int)
```

Comment: ahh, I see. You are correct, PERT is from pertdist. Thank you for your effort and for sharing - very helpful.

Comment: Time consumed decreased, when N = 1 000 000, from days to under one minute.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't make use of the capability of `PERT` (from `pertdist`) to draw more than one sample at a time.
Using that allows to reduce the complexity of vectorization a lot.
This is outlined in my second answer.
This answer is still useful for people that come here with different problems that they want to vectorize, as it uses a more general approach.

---

I think you may get a nice speed-up from vectorization.
When vectorizing, you would

1. replace `apply` with computing `"P"`, `"O"` and `"L"` each in a single go for the entire data frame
2. avoid the for loop, for example by using a 3D numpy array.

---

For step 1 you would do

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pert import PERT  # pertdist package

data = [
    [0.1, 0.14, 0.25, 50, 100, 150], 
    [0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 200, 250, 300], 
]
confidence = 4

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])

# Just pass None for size to get a vectorized version of PERT.
# I think this is undocumented behaviour of scipy.stats.beta,
# which PERT.rvs uses unter the hood
df["P"] = PERT(df["A"], df["B"], df["C"], confidence).rvs(None)
df["O"] = np.random.binomial(np.ones(len(df), dtype=int), df["P"])
L = PERT(df["D"], df["E"], df["F"], confidence).rvs(None)
df["L"] = np.where(df["O"] == 1, L, 0).astype(int)  # replaces ... if ... else ...
sum(df["L"])
```

Now I have computed one result, but we need `N`. Doing this in one go is a bit more tricky. This is step 2. One idea is not to use a 2D data frame, but a 3D numpy array (a 3D tensor).
Luckily `PERT` also supports this.

```
import numpy as np
from pert import PERT  # pertdist package

data = np.array([
    [0.1, 0.14, 0.25, 50, 100, 150], 
    [0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 200, 250, 300], 
])
N = 1000
confidence = 4

data_N = np.array([  # there is probably a faster way to do this
    data
    for _ in range(N)
])
print(data_N.shape)  # 1000, 2, 6 => 3D array/tensor

A = data_N[:, :, 0]
B = data_N[:, :, 1]
C = data_N[:, :, 2]
D = data_N[:, :, 3]
E = data_N[:, :, 4]
F = data_N[:, :, 5]


P = PERT(A, B, C, confidence).rvs(None)
print(P.shape)  # 1000, 2 => P values for each row of the original df, 1000 times
# independently drawing samples for each value in P
O = np.random.binomial(np.ones_like(P, dtype=int), P)
L = PERT(D, E, F, confidence).rvs(None)
L = np.where(O == 1, L, 0).astype(int)  # replaces ... if ... else ...
data1 = np.sum(L, axis=1)  # sum over L for each of the N samples
print(data1.shape)  # 1000, => 1000 results

for percent in [10, 25, 50, 75, 90]:
    print(np.percentile(data1, percent))
```

Comment: I think it's a step in the right direction but PERT only accepts 1D-array/series/list.

Comment: In that case, part 1 should still work and give you a speed-up. Part 2 may also work when you extract all the values from abc that you need, flatten that, pass it to PERT and reshape the result again to separate the rows and the 1000 samples in two dimensions.

Comment: If PERT is from `pertdist`, it fully supports vectorization, also with 3D inputs. See edited answer.